# "Post Your Answer" button appears to the side of the email checkbox, instead of below it as before

Tags: bug, design, email

If email notifications for the inbox are disabled, a checkbox appears next to questions and answers asking if the user wants to be emailed if they receive responses to their posts. On answers, this checkbox used to appear *above* the button to post or discard the answer. However, this is now instead appearing to the side of it:

[image: Post answer button appears in the wrong spot]

Can this please be moved back to the spot it used to be in?